How to convert from Google My Maps to Google Maps list?
I have a saved map in Google My Maps that I would like to convert to a Google Maps "list" (such as this one).
Google My Maps has a feature that allows exporting a map as a KML or KMZ file, 

but I did not find an complemetary feature in Google Maps that allows importing a list.

Google Maps does not support importing data into lists.
The following functionality is supported:

Create or Delete a list
Add or Remove a place
Share a list
Hide a list
Export list data via Google Takeout

More info: Create a list of places
